# Solving the integral equation $y(x) = 3 + 2\int_1^x t y(t) dt $ by reducing it to a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

> Solve the integral equation
>   $$y(x) = 3 + 2\int_1^x t \ y(t) \ dt  $$

First I solved for the integral equation. Then  I'm told to differentiate and I get

$${dy \over dx} = 2 x  y(x) $$

Then I see that they're separable and I use that so I take both of the integrals after arranging the functions. What I get is

$$ \ln(y(x))=x^2+C$$

---

**This I don't get, however:**
$$y(x) = C_1  \exp(x^2)$$

Where does this come from?

---

Now I choose an initial value for the first equation and I choose $ x=1$

$$ y(1) = 3 + 0 = 3$$

Now here's the problem

After this it's supposed to be $C_1= 3/e$

and the solution is

$$ y(x) = 3 \exp(x^2-1)$$

I understand everything up til choosing the initial value but i'm guessing it might be arbitrary however what happens with the $C_1$? How is this calculated? Everything gets really confusing here.

Comment: $\displaystyle\,{\rm y}\left(\, 0\,\right)=3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ln(y(x))=x^2+C$$
$$e^{\ln(y(x))}=e^{x^2+C}$$
$$y(x)=e^{x^2}e^{C}$$

$e^{C}$ is just a number, so let $C_{1}=e^{C}$:

$$y(x)=C_1e^{x^2}$$

$C_1$ is just another way of expressing our constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you get $\ln|y(x)|=x^2+C$, hence $y(x) = \pm e^{x^2}e^C$. Or $y\equiv 0$, which is a solution we lost when dividing by $y$. A neat way to put all these together is to write $y(x) =  C_1e^{x^2}$ where $C_1$ is a new constant, $C_1=\pm e^C$ or $C_1=0$ (in other words, $C_1$ can be any real number). This is done all the time with ODE that lead to $\ln(y) = \dots$.

At the last stage we have multiple ways to write down the solution, because, e.g., 
$$3e^{x^2-1} = \frac{3}{e} e^{x^2}$$
Which form you choose does not matter; different people will arrive at different forms, depending on when how chose to use the initial condition.